# Array size trouble on ARM Cortex M4

Tags: c, arrays, static, arm, cortex-m

I am doing some C programming on a Texas Instruments Tiva C Series LaunchPad (TM4C123G), based on ARM Cortex M4.

I have a problem with arrays that seems to be smaller than they should be. This example should illustrate the problem:

```
uint8_t* data;
static uint8_t d1[32];
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    d1[i] = i+65;
}
data = d1;
```

The content in data should be

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`
```

but is instead

```
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWX plus 8 non-printable characters
```

If I define d1 like this

```
static uint8_t d1[35];
```

all 32 bytes from 'A' to '`' is available in the array.

To me it is very strange that the array seems to be shorter than it really is. I would like to know how this can happen and how to fix the problem.

Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Don't do `i + 65` it can be confusing specially when you can do `i + 'A'`.

Comment: The question does not indicate lack of `nul` terminator, it says the last 8 chars of the array are corrupted. Pehaps a misbehaving interrupt function, with the sympton removed by lengthening the array?

Comment: @WeatherVane then why `static uint8_t d1[35];` works as expected?

Comment: @iharob I wondered why lengthening by 3 is enough, but then UB is UB, and we don't know the exact cause.

Comment: We need [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: static allocation would happen in a global scope, high chance that's getting overwritten. try to allocate buffer somewhere else, may be at stack.

Comment: Debugging tip: dump the _values_ of the "non-printable" bytes (%u or %x) - are they the same every time? Do they look suspiciously like addresses, or other recognisable data values from elsewhere in your code? Things like that generally help narrow down odd behaviour. That said, a) does it still happen if you make the array length some other exact multiple of 8? and b) do you know where all your stack pointers are?

Answer (score 4):

The length of the array is 32, and you assign a value to each element of it.

So if you loop over your array, and print each character *individually*, all is fine.

If you print the *whole array* using `printf("%s\n")`, your array is treated as a pointer to the start of a string. And that one must be terminated by a `\0`. Otherwise `printf` will continue to print until it finds a `\0` from the starting address on upwards.

Comment: I have tried printing the chars individually with printf using "%c". Also as the whole string using "%s", with and without null-termination. The problem is still there. I have also tested the code on my PC and it works like it should, printing all 32 characters. So I think the problem is ARM-related.

Comment: Then please show the full code with Makefile. What is the target of `printf`? Redirected via UART? Possibly one of the "[]\" characters trigger a terminal command or delete previous output. Possibly the problem is somewhere else, and the three additional bytes "save" you.